# Check for changes of JSON contents when app is not running

Tags: iphone, ios, json, notifications, push-notification

The app executes a JSON request, serializes the results and loads it into a tableView at each app launch.

I'm looking for a solution which also checks for updates of the JSON feed when the app is not running and informs the user with a red notification badge on the app icon.

Is this only possible with push notifications? This might be a problem because there is no possibility to have a SSL certificate on the server and the server will not be able to send a specific notification via JSON when the contents changed (contents are in a MySQL database).

Answer (score 1):

Right, you can't really do that. I think the best approach if you don't want to implement push (which is not too had, but certainly will take you longer than an hour...) is to create a MD5 hash of the JSON content and hash the new JSON enabling a very quick and accurate determination of whether or not something changed.

Another thing you might consider if you don't want push is an email attachment. It avoids push, but it's not particularly elegant. The idea is you register your app as handling the type of attachment you send, then when the email is received and the user taps the email attachment your app opens. I have used this answer: 
[How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2774343/189804) 
to do this and it works well.

Comment: I think the email idea will not be an option in this case because the users are unknown/not defined and they should not register with there emails. What exactly do you mean with the hashing the JSON content to determine updates? It would be great if you could provide an example. A SSL certificate on the JSON server is still needed?

Comment: Just a MD5 or SHA or similar hash function, it generates a (practically) unique string given some text as input. If you get 100k of JSON text and hash it, then you get 100k of JSON text some time later and the hashes compute to be the same result then you can safely ignore that second JSON string because it's the same information you already have - and you didn't have to turn it into cocoa objects and parse all the values to find that out.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, thats only available through push notifications.